# Magento get products next by price

Tags: magento

I need to get a collection of products next by price for specific product in some category.
For example: I have product **White Shoes**, it is located in **Shoes** category. I need to get next five products, that has higher price than **White Shoes** in **Shoes** category, and five products that has lower price.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar task, and here what I've done:

```
        $customerGroupId = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();

        $coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $adapter = $coreResource->getConnection('catalog_read');
        $prevSelect = $adapter->select()
            ->from(array('i' => $coreResource->getTableName('catalog/product_index_price')), array())
            ->join(
                array('p' => $coreResource->getTableName('catalog/category_product')),
                'p.product_id = i.entity_id',
                array('product_id')
            )
            ->where('p.category_id = ?', $categoryId)
            ->where('i.customer_group_id = ?', $customerGroupId)
            ->where('i.website_id = ?', $websiteId)
            ->where('p.product_id != ?', $product->getId())
            ->where('i.final_price < ?', $finalPrice)
            ->order('i.final_price DESC')
            ->limit(self::PRODUCTS_BLOCK_SIZE);

        $lowerIds = array_reverse($adapter->fetchCol($prevSelect));

        $nextSelect = $adapter->select()
            ->from(array('i' => $coreResource->getTableName('catalog/product_index_price')), array())
            ->join(
                array('p' => $coreResource->getTableName('catalog/category_product')),
                'p.product_id = i.entity_id',
                array('product_id')
            )
            ->where('p.category_id = ?', $categoryId)
            ->where('i.customer_group_id = ?', $customerGroupId)
            ->where('i.website_id = ?', $websiteId)
            ->where('p.product_id != ?', $product->getId())
            ->where('i.final_price > ?', $finalPrice)
            ->order('i.final_price ASC')
            ->limit(self::PRODUCTS_BLOCK_SIZE);

        $higherIds = $adapter->fetchCol($nextSelect);

        $lowerSliced = array_slice($lowerIds, -self::PRODUCTS_BLOCK_SIZE);
        $requiredFromHigher = self::PRODUCTS_BLOCK_SIZE - count($lowerSliced);
        $similarIds = array_merge(
            $lowerSliced,
            array_slice($higherIds, 0, $requiredFromHigher)
        );

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('product_url')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $similarIds))
            ->setPage(1, self::PRODUCTS_BLOCK_SIZE);
```

Comment: What makes this better than my solution? Not trying to be petty, just looking to learn!

Comment: The last solution is better, because of the following situation: for example, if there are no 5 products, lower by price (less than 5), anyway, I will get a pack of self::PRODUCTS_BLOCK_SIZE products

Comment: @Snowcore - Not sure I understand that. If what you actually wanted was "a block of the 5 lowest priced products around product X"... that was not made clear.

Answer (score 4):

This can probably be cleaned up from an efficiency standpoint, but hopefully you get the gist of it. There are two variables you'll need to set, `$product` which is probably your **White Shoes** product as a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` object and `$category` which is your **Shoes** category as a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` object.

**UPDATE**

This is a better way to do it without loading the entire product collection for `$category`.

```
// Load up to 5 products with price <= $product
$fiveLower = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    // Add whatever attributes you want here
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array(
        'name',
        'product_url',
        'small_image',
    ))

    // $category is an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)

    // Both of these are required to get the price
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice()

    // Filter out the current product by id
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => $product->getId()));

// Filter by final_price <= $product and limit to 5.
$fiveLower->getSelect()
          ->having('final_price <= ?', $product->getFinalPrice())
          ->order('final_price')
          ->limit(5, 0);

// Load up to 5 products with price > $product
$fiveHigher = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array(
        'name',
        'product_url',
        'small_image',
    ))
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice();

$fiveHigher->getSelect()
           ->having('final_price > ?', $product->getFinalPrice())
           ->order('final_price')
           ->limit(5, 0);

echo 'These are the lower priced items:' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($fiveLower as $item) {
    echo $item->getName() . ' - ' . $item->getFinalPrice() . PHP_EOL;
}

echo 'These are the higher priced items:' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($fiveHigher as $item) {
    echo $item->getName() . ' - ' . $item->getFinalPrice() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but here we will have performance issue: your code will load all products in specific category, but only 10 products required.

Comment: @Snowcore I've updated my answer to limit the `SELECT` to 5 products higher and 5 products lower or equal.